# Woocommerce - how to add text if no product variation options are selected?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Thanks to another thread I was able to hide the price of variable products if no variation options are selected by the user. Could I now add the text:

```
 <p>Make a selection to see the price</p>
```

I'm not even sure if it's possible, but thanks for taking the time to even read this.

Comment: You should add the link of the other thread that allow you to hide the price of variable products if no variation options are selected in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this JQuery code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
check_variations ();
$(".product-type-variable .variations select").change(function(){
    check_variations ();
});  
function check_variations () {
    var variationsarr = [];
    $('.product-type-variable .variations').find('select').each(function( value ) {
        variationsarr.push($(this).val());
    });
    var emptyvariation = true;
    for (i = 0; i < variationsarr.length; i++) { 
        if (variationsarr[i]) {
            emptyvariation = false;
            break;
        } 
    }
    if (emptyvariation) {
        $('.product-type-variable .variations').after('<p class="empty-variations-text">Make a selection to see the price</p>');
        $("span.woocommerce-Price-amount amount").hide();
    } else {
        $("p.empty-variations-text").remove();
        $("span.woocommerce-Price-amount amount").show();
    }   
}
```

});